# Using GPS data in Application

Tags: gps

I want using GPS data (I got it from $GPRMC) in an desktop application(that uses from mappoint 2009). I get the latitude & longitude, but when I check these points on map, I see the result is incorrect (for example My Data is: ***43.412 N, 79.369 W*** ; but the correct point is: ***43.686 N, 79.616 W*** ).
 I guess, I must use a correction method before use; I try *"Projection method"* like *"Miller"* or *"Mercator"*, but those aren't effective.
Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same coordinate systems? E.g. WGS-84 or something else?

Comment: Can you explain, I don't know what you say.

Comment: If your GPS returns coordinates in a datum (say, WGS-84) that is different from what is used on your map, results will be wrong.